# Select all entries where somewhere in their string is `h`, after that, there is a `e`, `l` and `o`

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Given are entries in a column `wort` in a table `woerter` like this

```
henlo
oenlh
olneh
```

I am looking for a sqlite command that lists all entries of `word` containing `h` `e` `l` `o`(for the sake of example, in fact those letters are always different) - in that order. So in this example the result should be

> henlo

as there is

`he`n`lo`

In other words: Select all entries where somewhere in their string is `h`, after that, there is a `e`, `l` and `o`. It does not need to be right after it, but somewhere after it. For instance:

> ssssshssssssessssssslsssossssso

would be in the results,

> ssosssssossssshssssssesssssssls

would not.

My approach so far:

> SELECT * FROM woerter WHERE wort LIKE 'h%' AND wort LIKE '%e%'  AND
>   wort LIKE '%l%'  AND wort LIKE '%o'

which is flawed because it does not properly integrate the order for e and l and it requires h and o to be at the beginning and end.

Comment: Does the "elo" need to be in that order - ie would "xxxhxxxloexx" match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use wildcard's in the middle of strings

```
SELECT * FROM woerter WHERE wort LIKE '%h%e%l%o%'
```

This searches for any word that has N characters, followed by `h`, followed by N characters, followed by `e`, etc.

The `%` wildcard matches any number of characters and by putting all this in a single condition you ensure that the characters are in the correct order.

To quote from [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A percent symbol ("%") in the LIKE pattern matches any sequence of zero or more characters in the string

Your conditions don't quite allow for the character to appear in any place in the string. As the percent symbol is a wildcard `like 'h%'` would only be true if the `h` was at the *beginning* of the string. Similarly with `like '%o'` the `o` must be at the end of the string.

This means that you're selecting any word that begins with `h`, has an `e` and a `l` somewhere in the string and ends in `o`.